# PostgreSQL CASE expression with CROSSTAB

Tags: postgresql

I have a table A with 3 columns :

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| user_id | amount spent |    timestamp    |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2433036 | 59,95        | 01.04.2018 6:34 |
|  139280 | 129          | 01.04.2018 3:09 |
|  139280 | 14,95        | 01.04.2018 3:15 |
| 2498579 | 14,95        | 02.04.2018 6:45 |
| 1548313 | 29,95        | 02.04.2018 7:08 |
| 2105392 | 14,95        | 03.04.2018 7:07 |
|  188470 | 29,95        | 03.04.2018 8:54 |
| 2433036 | 59,95        | 22.03.2018 6:34 |
|  139280 | 129          | 24.03.2018 3:09 |
|  139280 | 14,95        | 25.03.2018 3:15 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
```

I need to create 3 groups based on the total amount user spent (user's LTV) and make a table where I can see how much money each group brings per day. The table must look this way:

```
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
|    date    | < $ 50 | $ 50 - $ 99 | $ 100 + |
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
| 01.04.2018 | 0      |          60 |      90 |
| 02.04.2018 | 14,95  |          75 |     150 |
| 03.04.2018 | 14,95  |          35 |     125 |
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
```

I have done the aggregating part with CASE WHEN expression, but stuck with the later merging. Can someone help with the case?

```
SELECT user_id,  SUM(amount_spent) AS total_amount,
CASE    
WHEN (sum(amount_spent) < 50) THEN '< $ 50' 
WHEN (sum(amount_spent) < 100) THEN ' $ 50 - $ 100' 
ELSE ' > $ 100' 
END AS Category 
FROM TableA 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This code produces aggregating for each user.

Comment: Show what you've done

Comment: Note: there is no *CASE statement* (or clause) . `CASE ...` is a *conditional expression*

Comment: Based on the example of the output you want, I thought you wanted a table where `< $ 50` etc is a column name. Your query is selecting it as a value. Which do you want?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wanted a table where categories are columns (column names)